# Find a key in a BBST for which sum of values of keys smaller then it - is maximal

Tags: avl-trees, rank

I'm required to describe an implementation of a data structure that holds key,value pairs, which can be **signed integers**.

We need to be able to init() in O(1), insert(x) in O(logn), delete(x) in O(logn) and sumPrevious(x), which returns sum of **values** of the keys that are smaller than key 'x', in O(logn).
An AVL rank tree, which rank is sum of values in sub-tree, should do the trick. So far so good.

Now I need to also implement maxSumPrevious(), which returns the key 'k' for which 'sumPrevious(k)' is maximal, in O(1).
This is where I got stuck. Since inserting or deleting an element changes the 'sumPrevious' of ALL the elements bigger than it. I tried going in the direction of a different rank that updates in insertion/deletion, but it lead to nowhere.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you credit the original source where you saw this problem?

Comment: Let `maxSumPrevious(n)` be the max prefix sum in the subtree $n$. For a node $n$ with children $\ell$ and $r$, $maxSumPrevious(n) = \max(maxSumPrevious(\ell), sum(\ell) + maxSumPrevious(r))$.

Comment: @Dmitry, clever!  That sounds like the main idea of a solution, i.e., an answer.  Perhaps write that as an answer rather than as a comment, so we can upvote it?  I think it's better to have that in an answer, even if it is very concise, than a comment.

Comment: @D.W. Taken from one of my uni exams in data structures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add some additional data in each node, namely:

- the maximum sum of values of previous nodes **in the subtree**;
- the key **in the subtree** that reach this maximum sum.

It is clear that with this data, you can get `maxSumPrevious()` in $\mathcal{O}(1)$ time, but you would need to update the insertion and deletion of a node.

I will try to give details for insertion, deletion is done in similar ways. Suppose then that you want to insert $(k, v)$ in a tree $T$:

- if $T$ is empty, create a single node `x` such that `x.MSPV = 0` (MSPV stands for "max sum previous values") and `x.keyMSPV = k`;
- otherwise, make an usual insertion in BBST, and for each modified node `x` (by insertion in one child of `x` or after a rotation):

  - `x.MSPV` is the largest among the following:

    - `x.left.MSPV` if the corresponding key is in the left child;
    - `x.left.sumValues` if the corresponding key is in the root `x`;
    - `x.left.sumValues + v + x.right.MSPV` if the corresponding key is in the right child.
  - `x.keyMSPV` can be updated depending on the key that defines `x.MSPV`.

Those additional operations are done in $\mathcal{O}(1)$ time for each node, so the total complexity stays $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$.